# Database Query working on DBMS directly but not in Java

Tags: java, jpql

I am trying to do things before processing Ingest to [KIT DataManager](http://datamanager.kit.edu/index.php/kit-data-manager) ([Code on GitHub](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base), it runs on tomcat7) with a "Staging Processor" …

adding a custom Staging Processor

```
package edu.kit.dama.mdm.content.mets;
```

…

```
public class TryQuota extends AbstractStagingProcessor {
```

…

```
@Override
public final void performPreTransferProcessing(TransferTaskContainer pContainer) throws StagingProcessorException {
```

…

trying to get user data

… this works

```
        UserData userResult = null;
        try {
            userResult = mdm.findSingleResult(
                        "Select u FROM UserData u WHERE u.email=?1",
                        new Object[]{"dama@kit.edu"},
```

standard `email` of admin user with `userid` 1

```
                        UserData.class
                    );
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccessAttemptException e2) {
            System.out.println("exception on extracting userid");
                    e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("KIT DM ID: " + userResult.getUserId());
        }catch(Exception e4) {
            System.out.println("exception on output for userid");
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }
```

trying to get quota from UserQuota

and on the other hand, the corresponding implementation doesn't do the job here (that I want to get working)

```
        Number UserQuota = null;
        try {
            UserQuota = mdm.findSingleResult(
 //SQL would be: "SELECT quota FROM userquota WHERE uid=?;"
 //JPQL is …
                    "Select q.quota FROM UserQuota q WHERE q.uid=?1",
                    new Object[]{1},
                    Number.class
            );
        } catch (UnauthorizedAccessAttemptException e2) {
            System.out.println("exception on userquota");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("quota is: " + UserQuota );
```

`UserQuota` is still null here

DB is PostgreSQL, Table is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE userquota_seq       
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO MINVALUE;

CREATE TABLE userquota
( 
   id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('userquota_seq'),
   uid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   quota DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,        
   CONSTRAINT uid_key UNIQUE (uid), 
   CONSTRAINT fk_uid FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users(id)     
);
```

This quota I want to get from db in the processor

```
INSERT INTO userquota (id, uid,quota) VALUES ( 0, 1, 1048576 );
```

So mainly I want to get the entry for the ingesting user (here 1) from db: `1048576` as a Long.

Any hints welcome on how to proceed on these things.

Comment: Sorry for silly question. Did you commit inserted userquota?

Comment: yes, the query gives the expected answer in `psql`, but I seem to lack understanding the Java part.

Comment: A parameter in JDBC is only specified with `?` not with `?1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OP is not using JDBC, but some [homegrown helper API](http://ipelsdf1.lsdf.kit.edu/kdm/javadoc/edu/kit/dama/mdm/core/IMetaDataManager.html) by a [German university](http://www.kit.edu/).

Comment: `Select u FROM UserData u WHERE u.email=?1` doesn't work in PSQL, because it is not valid SQL syntax. Valid syntax would be `Select u.* FROM UserData u WHERE u.email='dama@kit.edu'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name didn't say JDBC, that's how the first part works – I see the same on several places on the GitHub, e.g. [1](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base/blob/e5fa04576b646a93229d9c53f4d23cd3fc3bcefa/MetaDataManagement/MDM-Content/src/main/java/edu/kit/dama/mdm/content/oaipmh/impl/SimpleOAIPMHRepository.java#L146) or [2](https://github.com/kit-data-manager/base/blob/c4f062bc34e79d0f3079a056ef0a8551f319ea60/Staging/Service/src/main/java/edu/kit/dama/staging/util/StagingConfigurationPersistence.java#L170); I am not at all experienced in Java, but it seems to be right here.

Comment: @Andreas I know, that I pointed out myself… the question rather is how to get the second working… as stated in the title working on DBMS, but not in Java. But updated the question to clarify on that matter.

Comment: If you know, why did you say *"why does the query work here, while on psql it does not?"*

Comment: got a hint that this is called JPQL; so edited the Q

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732860#comment74509580_43732860), the following statement is invalid SQL syntax:

`SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.email=?1`

Instead, according to above comment the correct syntax would be:

`SELECT u.* FROM UserData u WHERE u.email='dama@kit.edu'`

Comment: it was clarfied that the question is about JPQL and not SQL

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a class `UserQuota`[1](https://github.com/s72785/kitdm-base-1.4/commit/3c0b383ef6d4cf716b4ac0985c05ab19e547d98c) so JPQL can work here.
As I did not find a way around, I first copied class `UserData`, dropped everything I had no use of and changed the members according to my database table `userquota`. This also means when extending the db table this class needs to be altered as well.

A very important part I had no clue about is that this new class also needs to be registered for tomcat7 in `persistence.xml`, also here copied over from the entry for `UserData`.